# How do I re-instantiate original prefab after an object in that prefab has been destroyed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers

My problem is that my Original prefab is not being instantiated with all of its components. This is because after certain events, those objects get destroyed. But When I instantiate the prefab I want it to have all of its objects again. Does anyone know what I can do about this?

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.name.Contains ("Player"))
    {


        if(count == 0){
            Debug.Log("Enemy Collision");
            Instantiate(ground,new Vector3(distance, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(ground);

            distance = distance+ 40.31f;

            count=1;
        }

        else{
            Debug.Log("Enemy Collision");
            Instantiate(ground,new Vector3(distance, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(ground);

            distance = distance + 40.31f;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't destroy the prefab -- just destroy the newly instantiated object (assuming that's your intention):

```
var groundToBeDestroyed = Instantiate(ground, new Vector3(distance, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
Destroy(groundToBeDestroyed);
```